# bar chart saved as html file using mpld3 shows x-axis ticks on top

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, mpld3

I have a python code that stores the barchart as html file using the mpld3 save_html method. However, when I render the html file, the barchart shows x-axis ticks on the top as shown below.

[image]

I don't want the **ticks to be shown at all & also no tick labels** but want the x-axis line at the bottom. I thought I had done the required steps to prevent that from happening. Please see the code below. 
I would greatly appreciate any help here. I am blanking out.

```
 fig1,ax1=plt.subplots()
      dsize=fig1.get_size_inches()    
      fig1.set_size_inches((dsize[0]/2)*(1.5),(dsize[1]/2)*(1.25))

      m_colors=  ['red','green','blue','yellow','black','cyan','aqua','brown','coral','magenta','khaki','indigo','lavender','navy','olive','pink','plum','teal','tan','violet','wheat','orchid']
     bucket=['apple','banana','orange','lemon','pineapple']
     counts=[10,20,5,16,2]
     rects = ax1.bar(bucket,counts,color=m_colors)
     ax1.set_xlabel('Service Types')


ax1.set_ylabel('Anomalous Flow per Service Type')
ax1.tick_params(axis='x',which='both',bottom='off',top='off',labelbottom='off')
ax1.xaxis.set_label_position('bottom') 
for rect in rects:
    height = rect.get_height()
    ax1.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
            '%d' % int(height),
            ha='center', va='bottom')
#leg=ax1.legend((rects),(unique))

legend_font_props = FontProperties()
legend_font_props.set_size('xx-small')
leg=ax1.legend((rects),(bucket),loc='upper right',prop=legend_font_props)


mpld3.save_html(fig1,"test.html")
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]. Provide such a reproducible example, if you want help here.

Comment: thanks for the tip - took out the un-necessary code..  hope I had trimmed it enough.

Comment: This is partially about unnecessary code, but much more importantly about reproducibility. You can check if your example is complete and verifiable by copy and pasting the code from the question to a new file and running it. You will find out it will not run, hence its not a [mcve].

Comment: agree - thanks. i will edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mpld3 is not perfectly recreating matplotlib figures, it only tries to get close to the same appearance. In this case it seems to have problems replicating the axis parameters.

If you replace the lines

```
ax1.tick_params(axis='x',which='both',bottom='off',top='off',labelbottom='off')
ax1.xaxis.set_label_position('bottom')
```

by

```
ax1.set_xticks([])
```

The result would look like

[image]

which seems close to what you want.